# Javascript not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to HTML and trying to get the output of the following program but unable to get the output. I don't know whats wrong please help...

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="pink">
    <script src="valid.js" type="text/javascript" >

    </script>
        <form id="frm">
<center>
    <table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
        <tr>
            <td  align="center" style="vertical-align:middle"><font size="6">Login<font> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td  align="center" style="vertical-align:middle"><font size="4">User id <font></td><td>       :<input type="text" id="User"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  align="center" style="vertical-align:middle"><font size="4">Password<font></td><td>:<input type="password" id="pass"></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="Submit" value="Submit" object.onclick=valid()></td>

        </tr>
```

and the script is

```
function valid() {
  var x=document[frm][user].value;
  var y=document[frm][pass].value;
  if(x===null||x==="") {
    alert("Enter the user id and password");
    return false;
  }
  else if(x==="user"||y==="password") {
    alert("User id and password is correct");
      return true;
  }
  else
    alert("Wrong password or user id");
}
```

Please help I am trying to execute above program, but the Javascript is not working.

Comment: Please define "not working" more clearly.

Comment: remove all the <br/> tags from the javascript code.

Comment: Is it the complete code ?? Something seems missing in the html code

Comment: I don't "no" what you want it to do because you haven't told us what it should be doing.

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: object.onclick=valid()   - problem is here

Comment: `<input type="Submit" value="Submit" object.onclick=valid()>` `object.onclick` is not an attribute. No click handler will be attached. Moreover, you probably don't want to attach to `click` on a submit button; attach to `submit` on a form.

Comment: Please review the rules in the help center. "Plz help, idk what 2 do, gimme teh codez" questions are not appropriate for stackOverflow. Please keep this in mind in the future.

Comment: k Tjons ,i am new here and i will keep this in mind :-)

Comment: Thank you. I have been in your place. I had to learn this when I first got here, too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your valid() function as below:

```
 function valid() {

    var x=document.getElementById("User").value;
    var y=document.getElementById("pass").value;
    if(x=="")
    {
    alert("Enter the user id and password");
    return false;
    }
    else
    if(x=="user" || y=="password")
    {
    alert("User id and password is correct");
    return true;
    }
    else{
    alert("Wrong password or user id"); 
    return false;}
}
```

Comment: Also, `object.onclick=valid()` should be `onclick="return valid();"`

Comment: Yes correct. @PaulRoub

Comment: @PaulRoub: Probably not. It should probably be a `submit` handler on the form.

Comment: Paul is right. If there is an error on the form it should not submit. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli: Right. Which is why `valid` should be on the `submit` event of the form, not the `click` event of a submit button.